# Unit test in didselectrowatindexpath in UItableview

Tags: ios, ocunit

I used the below code to call `UITableView`

```
-(void)testJumpSection

{
     NSIndexPath *indexPath1= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [viewControllerObject tableView:viewControllerObject.masterTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];
    int backButtonSection = viewControllerObject.backButtonSection;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath2= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];
    [viewControllerObject tableView:viewControllerObject.masterTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath2];
    int backButtonSection2 = viewControllerObject.backButtonSection;
    [viewControllerObject backButtonView:viewControllerObject.button1];
    int backButtonSectionTestValue = viewControllerObject.backButtonSection;
    STAssertTrue(backButtonSectionTestValue==1, @"TestJumpSection");
}
```

I am writing this test case for expand/collapse uitableview.When the user clicked on row at section 0 and then clicked on section 3.Now  user might be clicked on back button to navigate section 2.Now i have to get the result backButtonsection value to be decreased by 1.

It is work fine but, I am unable get the selected section value, and I am getting this error:

> [__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument"

any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  Can you show us your implementation for `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: post some more code .

Comment: do you have any problem to understand the error message?

Comment: yes,i am  having doubts on this error

Answer (score 0):

it is very clear that you call `stringByAppendingString:` on a `__NSCFConstantString` that have argument of `nil`.

a simple example will cause this problem is

```
[@"some string" stringByAppendingString:nil];
```

a more likely cause will be

```
NSString *str;
str = @"some string"
NSString *anotherStr = nil;
// some other code that should set anotherStr but did not
NSString *result = [str stringByAppendingString:anotherStr]; // error
```

so go to find out `stringByAppendingString:` and check their argument

BTW, you should know this from debugger anyway because it should tell you which line cause the problem.